# Lost Focus Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-5.0

I created an application in C # to address some needs of an existing application in the enterprise. Recently we had to buy another application to support billing. These applications running is as follows:

1st Application-> 2 Application -> 3 Application

When I do "Process.Start" for the third application "it opens but after a few seconds it loses focus for the 1st Application. Anybody know how can I avoid this?

Comment: The question is not very detailed. What happens with the 3rd Application window? Is it minimized/hidden? If so, you need to use FindWindow() and SetWindowPos (both are usable via pinvoke) to bring the window  (if any) of 3rd Application into front.

Comment: It us minimized and appears de 1st Aplication. In windows Mobile how do FindWindow() and SetWindowPos?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the window class and/or title and then can use FindWindow to get a window handle for the window:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindowW", SetLastError=true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Using the window handle you can change the window back to normal display using SetWindowPos:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

In example, if the window has a class name of "App 3"

```
...
    IntPtr handle;

    try
    {
    // Find the handle to the window with class name x
    handle = FindWindowCE("App 3", null);
    // If the handle is found then show the window
    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // show the window
        SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOSIZE);
    }
    }
    catch
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Could not find window.");
    }
```

To find the window's class and title, start the CE remote tool "CE Spy" (part of VS installation) when app 3 is started. Then browse thru the window list and look the app 3 window. Double click the entry in the list and you will get the class name and title of app 3.

Instead of the extra SetWindowPos you can also use the simple [ShowWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html) API:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);

enum ShowWindowCommands
{
    Hide = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    ShowMinimized = 2,
    Maximize = 3, // is this the right value?
    ShowMaximized = 3,
    ShowNoActivate = 4,
    Show = 5,
    Minimize = 6,
    ShowMinNoActive = 7,
    ShowNA = 8,
    Restore = 9,
    ShowDefault = 10,
    ForceMinimize = 11
}
...
    IntPtr handle;

    try
    {
    // Find the handle to the window with class name x
    handle = FindWindowCE("App 3", null);
    // If the handle is found then show the window
    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // show the window
        ShowWindow(handle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal);
    }
    }
    catch
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Could not find window.");
    }
```

For details about pinvoke of FindWindow and SetWindowPos see [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.FindWindowW) and MSDN. Best book about Win32 programming is Charles Petzold's Programming Windows.

When you started the process you need the OS give some time to settle the app (let's say 1-3 seconds), before you change the window.